# Discussing negative experiences on professional networks: acceptable or not?

Tags: linkedin, blogging

Is it suitable to post about a negative experience with a prominent online retailer on a professional network such as LinkedIn? I made several attempts to point out an issue that could be easily verified with just a few clicks or a single phone call, such as checking the delivery status on the carrier’s website. However, they unwaveringly relied on their system, which clearly contained an error. This reliance not only led to a significant loss of my time but also caused me considerable disappointment.

Comment: What would you hope to gain by doing so? What would be your desired outcome?

Comment: @joeqwerty I find this story both entertaining and insightful, revealing flaws in what's considered a perfect system. Hopefully, someone from the company will notice and resolve these issues.

Comment: Why don't you just contact them by phone or email? Posting on LinkedIn seems like the least effective way to do this with the least chance of being seen and affecting change.

Comment: @joeqwerty The situation is that I've reached out to them, and not just them, but others as well, multiple times through both email and phone.

Comment: It's acceptable, but usually LinkedIn is for professional self-promotion, and you should know that a potential employer can see all the posts you've made on LinkedIn. That is why not many people use LinkedIn to complain about companies, because it could paint them as complainers when looking for a job. In my opinion, that is what X-Twitter, or Yelp reviews (depending on the business), or many of the review sites out there, are for, and personally, I would use one of those sites instead of LinkedIn to make such a complaint.

Comment: How is this a "Workplace" topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The honest answer is that I'd save that sort of stuff for the likes of Glassdoor or other review-type sites.

There's two reasons:

1: If you are wanting to have a vent and a moan - go to Facebook.
2: Praise in Public, Criticize in private.

Now, by all means, find someone in a high-enough position on Linked-in and send them a direct message with your issues - but doing it in public is somewhat Gauche in my opinion

Comment: Depending on location, Trustpilot is also an excellent forum for consumer warnings.

Answer (score 5):

**Nope** - You wouldn't discuss this matter on your CV or during an interview or in-person networking event right? That's a good rule of thumb that it doesn't belong on LinkedIn.

I can understand the urge to vent about the issue you experienced but LinkedIn is just not the place for that sort of thing. Not only is it extremely unlikely to actually get you anywhere in terms of resolving your situation (customer-facing social media such as facebook and twitter or a review service like Google or Yelp is likely to be far more productive in this regard) but it's going to reflect negatively on *you*, as you'll come across as someone who doesn't understand professional norms - probably not going to be a deal-breaker or anything that serious but why would you risk sowing any little negative seeds on what is supposed to be your best professional front?

Comment: "in-person networking event right" - maybe the in-person networking events I go to are more informal, but I would.